# Is it possible to run durable azure functions on premises or locally

Tags: azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

just reading on azure durable functions for writing business process, and was wondering if this offering is necessarily bundled with azure, or if the runtime can be hosted on premises or locally etc ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes! You can run the Azure Functions (Normal or Durable Functions) on-premises rather than in Azure.

In 3 Ways, you can run Azure Functions on-premises:

1. Using Azure Functions Core Tools
2. Using Azure Functions Docker Container Image
3. Using KEDA (Kubernetes-based Event Driven Autoscaling) in which Azure Functions supports it.

Please refer to this [MSFT Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/hybrid/azure-functions-hybrid#running-azure-functions-on-premises) for more information.

Comment: fantastic, thanks for the clarification.... So essentially its use isn't dependent on an azure account, and can be used for free in production ?

Comment: In any of the above ways: For running locally, azure account is not required. For running in the cloud (production), Azure account (either free or pay-as-you-go subscription) is required. Refer the MSFT Doc which shows how to run locally as well as in cloud (production) for all of the 3 ways.